# Change cart items count dynamically in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I show cart's total item in `Detail.js` page's header which is coming from `Routes.js` file. I want to change that total when `Add to bag` button clicked. As I shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YJc3.png)
image. When I refresh my application it will updated but I want to change at same time. I found the solution for dynamic header using `react-native-router-flux` but for rightButton I don't know how to pass my updated variable to header.

**Routes.js** :

```
import {Actions, Router, Stack, Scene} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import IndividualDetail from '../screens/IndividualDetail/IndividualDetail';

export default class Routes extends Component<{}> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            bagCount: 0
        };
    }
    render() {
      const bagIcon = 
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => Actions.wishlist()} style={s.right_container}>
          <View style={s.icon_cont}>
            <View style={s.badge_cont}>
              <Text style={s.abdge_txt}>{this.state.bagCount}</Text>
            </View>
            <Icon name="shopping-cart" size={icon_size} color={colors.white}/>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>

      return (
         <View style={{flex:1}}>
           <Router navigationBarStyle={styles.navbar_style} tintColor="#fff" backTitle=" " titleStyle={styles.title_style}>
             <Stack key="root" hideNavBar={false} >
               <Scene hideNavBar={false} key="individual_detail" component={IndividualDetail}  title="Product Detail" renderRightButton={() => bagIcon}/>
             </Stack>
           </Router>
         </View>
      );
   }
}
```

**IndividualDetail.js**

```
 export default class IndividualDetail extends Component 
 {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         bagCount: 0
      };
    }

    _handleAddToBagBtn = () => {
       //Here I want to change bag total count at header
    }

    ...
 }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: pass handler as prop, search for `'react-native-router-flux pass props'`

Comment: @xadm, thanks for reply but I want to pass `this.state.bagCount` parameter in `Router.js` file from `IndividualDetail.js`. I refered that link which you had given but it redirects screens and in my case I don't want to redirect screens. Can you please give example for that?

Comment: google 'react update state in parent'